# Google Chrome extension returns "Uncaught No Chrome Web Store item link found."

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I've spent the past 2 hours looking through other answers for this, and still couldn't find an answer that fixed my problem. I've published an extension for my website and am trying to get inline installation working, but it's constantly returning "Uncaught No Chrome Web Store item link found".

In my , I've included the link
    `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fghfjmbmgejbkmbcjlgamcofpgphmdme">`

and the button that should install it is
`<button id='install' onclick="chrome.webstore.install('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fghfjmbmgejbkmbcjlgamcofpgphmdme', function(d){console.log('installed')}, function(e){console.log('not installed: '+e)});">Install</button>`

the function(d) and function(e) are included because one answer suggested the function REQUIRED a success and failure callback function, rather than optional like the webstore suggests.

At this point I can't include the website itself, but will try to set something up to allow it.

**Edit:** If it helps at all, the error says that the function is working fine, but that the issue is in extensions::webstore. So it seems to get through my javascript, then get stuck in Chrome's code.

Comment: This is what I have on the button: `onclick="chrome.webstore.install()"`. Also, it does not work if the domain is localhost.

Comment: @Granga The website is hosted, but it's password protected because it's in development, hence why I'm not including the website. I'm currently trying to set something up so that the page will still work if I put it in it's own section of the website.
I've tried simply putting `onclick="chrome.webstore.install()"` , but that didn't seem to work either, still the same error.

Comment: Another idea is to try with the ID of some popular extension and see if that one is also "not found". Depending on the result, you will know if the problem is in your html page or the Webstore extension settings/approval.

Comment: @Granga
Tried you method, and produced the same error. I found out there was also a `<p>` in the head. I thought this might be causing issues in the head. After I moved it, it started popping up with "Could not fetch data from the Chrome Web Store" error. After looking it up for a while I tried reloading the page again and the extension downloaded.
I'll continue trying to find the solution to the new error, but it appears the `<p>` tag was breaking the head. Chrome does not examine the source code, but Mozilla showed that the `</head>` was a "stray head tag", so the `<p>` was my problem.